# Angular save response data into variable

Tags: angular, http, httpresponse

```
user: User

this.httpService.getCurrentUser()
.subscribe(
    data => {
      this.user = JSON.parse(data["_body"]).value[0];
          console.log("1" +this.user)
         },
   error => console.error(error)
     );
console.log("2"+this.user);
```

So in this function I get my currentUser and put it into my variable and if i log my this.user the first time it has the correct information in it but on the second log it only says [object][object] but why? It seems like the response data is only in the variable during that function but lose it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `console.log("2"+this.user);` you tell to Javascript to convert that `this.user` object first to string (which is `[object Object]`) and then do concat with `2`.

Also remember that `console.log(2...)` will happen first. Because the `console.log(1...)` will happen AFTER fetching data from server.

Also I see you are assigning the response from server to `this.User` while your are printing out `this.user` - notice the capital U.

My guess is that you load an object from the server. Just use `console.log(this.user)` to what is the response.

Comment: makes no sense to me why does javascript think its supposed to convert it to string only on the second one ?

Comment: It would help if you provide the exact output. I think you have some default value in `this.user` therefore it prints expected output. While after fetching data from server you are assigning there an object.

Comment: What I actually trying to do is get the user object from my api then send it to my http.service (where all the http.get, http.post, http.patch stuff is) and put it into a variable with type user (user object has all the stuff i get from the api like id name and so on) in my http.service i have another function which returns the user i previously saved. So i can access to the currentUser from anywhere just by calling that function

Comment: why `getCurrentUser` returns observable then? It looks like  it should return just that user, right?

Comment: Its working now the Problem was that the http request of getcurrentUser() function is async that means the code after the subscription was executed earlier than the stuff in the subscription and so it tried to access data that was still on its way cuz of the async request.

Comment: @Kai yes, thats what the 2nd paragraph of my answer says :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have in mind that any subscription that you have, is an asynchronous code.

```
this.httpService.getCurrentUser()
.subscribe(
    data => {
        // This may or not (probably not) run first
      },
   error => console.error(error) // This may never run, if error doesn't occurs.
     );

// This will run after the subscription is made. Almost always before the success callback.
console.log("2"+this.user);
```

Anything that depends on a async response like an HTTP request, should be inside it.